# How to observe Button's onPressed function in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

When every Button's `onPressed` function invoked I want to insert another function `hookButtonOnPressed`.

example:

```
TextButton(
    onPressed: (){
          print('onPressedInvoked');    
    },
    child: Text('Test')
)

void hookButtonOnPressed() {
    print('hookButtonOnPressedInvoked');   
}
```

So when I press the `TextButton` I expect the console will show

```
hookButtonOnPressedInvoked
onPressedInvoked
```

Comment: What do you me an by observe? Do you want to retrieve values or call a specific method when pressing?@dowZhang

Comment: I want to call a specific method.

Comment: You can create specific widget TextButtonApp() , 
and inside this widget:
 onPressed(){
widget.onPressed();
hookButtonOnPressed();
}

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by creating a custom TextButton widget

```
void hookButtonOnPressed() {
  print('hookButtonOnPressedInvoked');
}

// custom Button Widget
class CustomTextButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function callback;

  CustomTextButton({
    required this.callback,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      onPressed: () {
        callback();
        hookButtonOnPressed();
      },
      child: const Text('Test')
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            CustomTextButton(callback:()=>{print("hello")}),
            CustomTextButton(callback:()=>{print("hello")}),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

output on pressing both buttons

```
hello
hookButtonOnPressedInvoked

hello
hookButtonOnPressedInvoked
```

Comment: I want to observe every button.

Comment: @dowZhang see the edited answer